# DAX calculate countrows with date filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this DAX formula which is working fine,  I want to add a date filter to filter for sales completed before DB Sales [date] 30/9/2022, but it does not like the date filters.  Any help and directions appreciated.

```
Sales Completed =
IF.EAGER (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'DB Sales' ),
        'DB Sales'[Status] = "Completed"
    ) + 0 = 0,
    BLANK (),
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'DB Sales' ),
        'DB Sales'[Status] = "Completed"
    ) + 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string to a date for comparison:

```
Sales Completed before Date = 
VAR _rows = 
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'DB Sales' ),
        'DB Sales'[Status] = "Completed",
        'DB Sales'[Date] < DATEVALUE("30/9/2022")
    )
RETURN
    IF (_rows = 0, BLANK(), _rows)
```